# Convert Uint8List image data to ImageGallerySaver saveFile String

Tags: image, flutter, file

how can I convert the Uint8List imagedata of the [Screenshot Package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot/example) to save it with the [ImageGallerySaver package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) saveFile command, which needs a string?

```
               TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _imageFile = null;
                  screenshotController
                      .capture()
                      .then((Uint8List image) async {
                    //print("Capture Done");
                    setState(() {
                      _imageFile = image;
                    });
                    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(); 
                    print("File Saved to Gallery");
                  }).catchError((onError) {
                    print(onError);
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  _imageFile = null;
                  screenshotController
                      .capture()
                      .then((Uint8List image) async {
                    //print("Capture Done");
                    String dir =
                        (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
                    File file = File("$dir/" +
                        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
                        ".png");
                    await file.writeAsBytes(image);

                    setState(() {
                      _imageFile = image;
                    });
                    final result =
                        await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(file.path);
                    print("File Saved to Gallery");
                  }).catchError((onError) {
                    print(onError);
                  });
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.change_history),
              ), // Thi
```